# Can't install lsphp56 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, litespeed

I tried to install PHP 5.6 with LiteSpeed SAPI for my OpenLiteSpeed Webserver on Ubuntu 18.04 from an official repository using this guide: https://www.litespeedtech.com/support/wiki/doku.php/litespeed_wiki:php:apt
But after adding the LiteSpeed Debian Repository command `sudo apt search lsphp56` gave me no result (the earliest version I can find is lsphp 7.0). Am I did something wrong or OLS stop to support lsphp56? Is there another way to install lsphp 5.6 on OLS?

Comment: By default, Debian 9 and Ubuntu 18.04 support only PHP 7.x compatible with OpenSSL 1.1.

Comment: Why not check out the repo https://rpms.litespeedtech.com/debian/pool/main/ itself? And if using a wholly outdated PHP version is the agenda, compiling from source might be in order. (Which would also be slightly more on-topic than just package installation.)

Comment: Did you get any errors while running the first `wget` command?